# NSSpeechSynthesizer get Siri voices on macOS

Tags: swift, macos, avfoundation, avspeechsynthesizer, nsspeechsynthesizer

Is there a way to get the Siri voices for `NSSpeechSynthesizer`? `NSSpeechSynthesizer.availableVoices()` does not list them, but maybe there is an undocumented trick or something?

I've also tried to use `AVSpeech​Synthesizer`, even tough it should be available on macOS 10.14+, I couldn't get it to read out loud …

I've used a Playground to test this with the following code from [NSHipster](https://nshipster.com/avspeechsynthesizer/):

```
import Cocoa
import AVFoundation

let string = "Hello, World!"
let utterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: string)

let synthesizer = AVSpeechSynthesizer()
synthesizer.speak(utterance)
```

Comment: "I couldn't get it to read out loud", could you specify what you tried?

Comment: @vrwim I basically used the code _zrzka_ suggested in his answer (I've updated mine as well). Though I still don't get my Mac to actually read out the string. Nevertheless my main goal was to get the (better) Siri voices. That seems to be impossible with public API's…

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Siri voice

I'm not aware of any trick to make the Siri voice available and I'm afraid it's impossible to make it working via public API.

- Both `NSSpeechSynthesizer` and `AVSpeechSynthesizer` do utilize `SpeechSynthesis.framework` (included in the `ApplicationServices.framework`).
- Quickly checked it and the function `BuildDefaultVoiceList(bool)` checks bundle identifier (via `PermitAllVoices` which compares it with `com.apple.VoiceOverUtility`, `com.apple.VoiceOver`, `com.apple.VoiceOverUtilityCacheBuilder`).
- There're other checks probably.

All the voices are stored in the `/System/Library/Speech/Voices` folder. Tried to copy the voice, change `Info.plist` values to make it look like another voice, but still not available/working.

How far do you want to go? Do you want to disable SIP, modify framework, preload your stuff, ... Is it worth it?

### `AVSpeech​Synthesizer` on macOS

It works, but it's buggy and you have to kill the service from time to time.

#### List of available voices

```swift
AVSpeechSynthesisVoice.speechVoices().forEach { voice in
    print("Name: \(voice.name) Language: \(voice.language) Identifier: \(voice.identifier)")
}
```

#### Speak

```swift
let utterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: "Ahoj, jak se máš?")
utterance.voice = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice(identifier: "com.apple.speech.synthesis.voice.zuzana.premium")

let synthesizer = AVSpeechSynthesizer()
synthesizer.speak(utterance)
```

#### Doesn't speak?

All the following methods (delegate) are called when you call `speak(utterance)` and it works as it should:

- [`speechSynthesizer(_:didStart:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avspeechsynthesizerdelegate/1619701-speechsynthesizer)
- [`speechSynthesizer(_:willSpeakRangeOfSpeechString:utterance:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avspeechsynthesizerdelegate/1619681-speechsynthesizer)
- [`speechSynthesizer(_:didFinish:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avspeechsynthesizerdelegate/1619700-speechsynthesizer)

Something's wrong if you get just the [`speechSynthesizer(_:didCancel:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avspeechsynthesizerdelegate/1619678-speechsynthesizer) method call and you have to kill the `speechsynthesisd` process:

```sh
kill `pgrep speechsynthesisd`
```

Then try again, it fixes the issue for me.

### Additional voices installation

- System Preferences - Accessibility - Speech
- System Voice - click & scroll down & select Customize...
- Select additional voice to install

Comment: Thanks a lot @zrzka for this in depth answer! My main goal was to get the Siri voices, but as you confirmed that doesn't seem to be possible. I was hoping to access them with the newer `AVSpeech​Synthesizer` API. Though if it points to the same framework as `NSSpeechSynthesizer ` I will stick with this for now.